# Python 3.6: when a value in a list changes, find the sum of the values in another list?

Tags: python, list, sum

```
A = ['1','1','1','3','3','4']

B = ['5','9','3','4','8','1']
```

When the value in list A changes, for example from 1 to 3.
Find the sum of the set of values in list B, for example sum of (5,9,3).
List A and B are the same size.

> In list A = ['1','1','1','3','3','4']
>   SEARCH -  **1)** where value changes from 1 to 3, **2)** where value changes from 3 to 4.
>
> In list B = ['5','9','3','4','8','1']
>    RESULT - **1)** sum only 5+9+3, **2)** sum only 4+8.

Is there a way to do this?
Because I cant think of a logical way to go around it.

My start to the code:

```
A = ['1','1','1','3','3','4']

B = ['5','9','3','4','8','1']


C=[int(value) for value in A]
print(C)

for i in C:
    if C[:-i] == C[:i]:
```

This would look through each neighbor value of A and see if they are same but i don't know how to relate this to list B's values.

Comment: Would you like to share your effort with us?. Else this is too broad because you're asking us to write code for you.

Comment: please provide expected output, and/or an attempt. ATM it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), where you show your own code, the result that you get and what you expect instead. This way it is much more likely that you get help quickly.

Comment: I've been trying to write the code for this but I am quite unclear on how to go about it. What I am trying to achieve is when value in list A changes from 1 to 3, find the sum of the values in next list, such as 5+9+3, from the point of the value change in list A, and so on and so on.

Comment: Another example is when value in list A changes from 3 to 4 then find the sum of only 4+ 8 in list B.

Comment: Why are you summing up 5+9+3 but not 4+8+1?

Comment: This example you give is good additional information. Please update the question with this extra example.

Comment: @M.Chan btw the way to think about problems like this is to try to come up with a more simple example. For instance what if you had `A = 1` and `B = 5`. (No longer lists, but single values). How would you detect that A has changed from 1 to, say, 3? If it does then the result would be the value of B.

Comment: @quamrana Hi, that would be a simpler example of my question yes. Basically detecting when a value changes in one list and then finding the sum of values in another list. It's quite hard to explain im sorry if its confused anyone.

Comment: @M.Chan. I think we understand what you are asking, I am just trying to make you think about the problem. This will be a vital skill for you as a programmer. However, to progress this question on Stack Overflow, you need to write *some* code yourself. That way we can understand how you are thinking about the problem.

Comment: @quamrana I understand that some code would be helpful but I don't know how to start this problem, so any of my coding wouldn't be very helpful.

Comment: @quamrana i added my coding progress to the question if it helps

Comment: @M.Chan. Ok, now you have added this: `C[:-i] == C[:i]` we can see that you have some mistaken thinking about slices.This expression compares the last `i` elements with the first `i` elements. Nothing to do with adjacent elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I understand that the list `A` itself is not going to change, but you expressed the idea of change meaning that the list has partitions where there are adjacent elements that are different, then a different solution comes to mind:

Given your original data:

```
A = ['1','1','1','3','3','4']

B = ['5','9','3','4','8','1']
```

We can use a `defaultdict` to group this data:

```
from collections import defaultdict
D = defaultdict(list)

for a, b in zip(A,B):
    D[a].append(int(b))
```

Just to show what we have collected:

```
for a, b in D.items():
    print(a,b)
>> 1 [5, 9, 3]
>> 3 [4, 8]
>> 4 [1]
```

Now we can compute some sums:

```
result = [sum(b) for a,b in D.items()]
print(result)
>> [17, 12, 1]
```

Notes about `defaultdict`:

When the instance is created:

```
D = defaultdict(list)
```

This creates a `defaultdict` which, when it encounters new keys will create an instance of the parameter. In this case it creates a new `list`

So each line:

```
D[a].append(int(b))
```

When `a` is a key that `D` has not seen before, a new `list` is created, which is returned, to which the `.append(....` is applied.

Comment: Thank you mate, that was exactly what was needed. I didn't know of defaultdict.

Comment: Now that's another question. Post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to think of a simpler problem:

Suppose you have:

```
A = 1
B = 5
```

How can we detect that A has changed?

We need to have retained a copy of `A` so that a comparison can be done if we think that a change has occurred:

```
A = 1
B = 5

old_A = A  # take a copy

# Detect a change:
if A != old_A:
    result = B
```

Now it looks like you have updated your question with a similar idea:

```
A = ['1','1','1','3','3','4']

B = ['5','9','3','4','8','1']

C = A[:] # take a copy
```

Now we have to detect changes:

```
# suppose that A is now ['3','3','3','3','3','4']
#      while C is still ['1','1','1','3','3','4']
comp = [ a!=c for (a,c) in zip(A,C)]

print(comp)
>> [True,True,True,False,False,False]
```

Now we know which numbers have changed we can pick the corresponding items from `B`:

```
result = [int(b) for c,b in zip(comp,B) if c] # note the int(b)
>> [5, 9, 3]
print(sum(result))
>> 17
```

So to review:

Note the use of copying of lists:

```
C = A[:]
```

Note the use of list comprehensions:

```
comp = [ x for y in z]
result = [ x for y in z if q]
```

Note the use of the `zip` function:

```
for (a,c) in zip(A,C)
```

I will leave it as an exercise to collapse the steps into the sum of a single list comprehension.

Comment: Hi, how would comp  be related back to list B?

Comment: I have used your steps and example but I don't seem to obtain the same results. For comp I get [False, False, False, False, False, False] and for sum(result) i get 0.

Comment: Then it seems you have not taken a copy of the list to use later in the comparison.

Comment: 'A = ['3','3','3','3','3','4']
B = ['5','9','3','4','8','1']
C = A[:] 
comp = [ A!=C for (A,C) in zip(A,C)]
print (comp)
result = [int(B) for C,B in zip(comp,B) if C] 
print(sum(result))'

Comment: This gives me comp = [False, False, False, False, False, False] and sum(result) = 0

Comment: Note the use of lowercase letter variables to represent the elements of the lists: `[ a!=c for (a,c) in zip(A,C)]`

Comment: I have editted it to lower case but still somehow obtain comp = [False, False, False, False, False, False] and sum(result) = 0

Comment: I suggest you post your code as another question, along with the actual and expected results. You will get more traction than with me debugging code I cannot see.

Comment: Okay, so I added 'A = ['3','3','3','3','3','4']
B = ['5','9','3','4','8','1']
C = A[:] 
C = ['1','1','1','3','3','4']
comp = [a!=c for (a,c) in zip(A,C)] 
print (comp)
result = [int(b) for c,b in zip(comp,B) if c] 
print(sum(result))' and now it gives me the same result as you but isn't that comparing separate lists rather than the values already inside one of the lists?

Comment: What do you expect? If variable `A` has a certain value at one point in time and a different value at a later point in time, how can you tell that there has been a change unless you know (ie have taken a copy) what it used to be like?

Comment: I think we might be thinking of different approaches but what I mean was finding the next change in value in list A, like A = ['1','1','1','3','3']. So that in list A, the value changes from the final 1 to the first 3. At the point of change it will compare the position of change with list B and sum the values of list B with the same range of unchanged values in list A. In my example the values inside the lists will always remain the same.

Comment: This is what happens when you don't show what results you actually expect. Are you expecting to get: `5+9+3` because they relate to the 'ones' and `4+8` because they relate to the 'threes' and `1` because that relates to the 'fours', so you want `5+9+3` and `4+8` and `1` which will be `17` and `12` and `1`?

Comment: I added a clearer example in the opening question, hopefully can explain. But yes your logic is now the same as mine. Thanks

Comment: Do the elements in list `A` always increase in value, or are they just sometimes different? eg could `A` contain: `[1,1,9,9,7,7,3,3,7,7]`?

Comment: it would always increase in value with multiple repeats of the same number. Like in this example A = ['1','1','1','3','3','3','4','4','4'] whereas values in list B can be any value with no pattern but always same size as list A, like B = ['4','8','3',2','9','7',8','1',2']